# Trying to find the longest sequence of number without six in random number

Tags: python-3.x

I have tried following code but it seems that it is only counting the numbers excluding six's and displaying the result. However what I want is to check the longest sequence without six's. I tried the Logic in my code but not working.

Function double_six () absolutely working fine but no_six() is not working.

here is sample output

10

4113644412

0

4

the 4 at the end should be 5 as longest sequence without six

```
from random import *

trial = int(randint(1, 10))
print(trial)
result = ''
for i in range(trial):
    init_num = str(randint(1, 6))
    result += init_num
print(result)

def double_six(result):
    last_dice = '0'
    counter = 0
    for i in range(trial):
        if result[i] == '6' and last_dice == '6':
            counter += 1
            last_dice = '0'
        else:
            last_dice = result[i]
    return counter
print(double_six(result))

def no_six(result):
    counter = 0
    length = 0
    previous = 0
    for i in range(trial):
        if result[i] == '6':
            length = counter
            if length > previous:
                previous = length
        else:
            counter +=1

    return  previous
print(no_six(result))
```

Comment: You are only counting the sequence at the left of the six.

Comment: It seems through my code that I am doing that but I need to find the longest sequence in result, but my code is not working

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
def no_six(result):
    s = str(result).split('6')
    l = 0
    for i in s:
        if l < len(i):
            l = len(i)
        if len(i) > l:
            l = i
    return(l)
        
print(no_six(result))
```

It splits the sequence using the six as reference and compares the length of each part.

```
print(no_six(44464444644))
# 4

print(no_six(643126))
# 4

print(no_six(515113366))
# 7
```

Comment: The code is not working for 643126 the outcome is 0 however it should be 4

Comment: still got the error with 515113366. Showing 0 for no_six ( )

Answer (score 0):

I think your original function just needed an if at the end to return counter when there were no sixes or when the current counter of no sixes was the longest.

```
def no_six(result):
    counter = 0
    length = 0
    previous = 0
    for i in range(trial):
        if result[i] == '6':
            length = counter
            if length > previous:
                previous = length
        else:
            counter +=1
    if counter > previous:
        return counter
    else:
        return  previous
print(no_six(result))
```